# Convert ProblemSteps Recorder tests to CodedUI tests?

Tags: windows, windows-7, coded-ui-tests

Is there any way to convert Problem Steps Recorder tests in Windows 7 created by my users, to CodedUI tests?

Comment: Unfortunately, "Problem" and "Steps" can't be separated in the title because of SO's [title filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/using-the-word-problem-in-titles).  Even [moderators do not have the rights to bypass it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115007/moderators-should-be-immune-to-the-word-filters-in-titles).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, no. I've been searching for that... a lot!